# cursor doesn't shift to new line after pressing enter key in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

i am making a text editor program using ncurses library file.but in my program i am not able to shift the cursor to new line after pressing `enter` key. I am using `switch case` to determine which Key is pressed and then changing the variables to determine the current position. All works fine but after pressing `Enter` the cursor doesn't move.
I am using `move(y,x)` function.

```
while((ch = getch())!= KEY_F(1))
{
    switch(ch)
    {
        case KEY_LEFT:
            if(posx>0)
            posx--;
                            //traverse left in my link list

            break;

        case KEY_RIGHT:
            if(posx<=cols && posx<cur_maxx)
                posx++;
                            //traverse right in my link list
            break;

        case 263:
            if(posx>0)
               posx--;
                           //delete one node in link list
            break;

        case KEY_ENTER:
            posx=0;
            posy=10;  //for testing 
                            //add new line at end of link list
            break;

        default:
             c=ch;
             getyx(stdscr,y,x);
             //add the character to the linked list based on its               
                             //position(insert at prev or append)

            break;

    }   

    clear();        
    traverse(mn);//it is for printing the characters
    move(y+posy,x+posx);

    refresh();

}
```

Everything works fine the left key and the right key but after pressing the enter key 
the cursor hang up at the previous position and the output came in new line.
How do I move the cursor successfully after pressing enter?
Is there any other approach to move the cursor(using ncurses) ?

Answer (score 0):

`KEY_ENTER` only refers to the keypad's enter button.

Unless that is what you was trying to do, try this:

```
case 13:         // Replaced KEY_ENTER with 13
        posx=0;
        posy=10;

        break;
```

You can leave the case you already have in there if you want to support the keypad's enter button as well.

Also, did you make a call to `keypad()`? If not try adding `keypad(winscr, TRUE)`.